# Should configuration files allow whitespace before comment lines?

Tags: bash

I am trying to implement a simple configuration file format according to [this Eric S. Raymond article](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch10s03.html) (which calls them "run-control" files).

> This exception aside, here are the normal style rules for run-control
>   syntaxes. Historically, they are patterned on the syntax of Unix
>   shells:
>
> Support explanatory comments, and lead them with #. The syntax should
>   also ignore whitespace before #, so that comments on the same line as
>   configuration directives are supported.
>
> Don't make insidious whitespace distinctions. That is, treat runs of
>   spaces and tabs, syntactically the same as a single space. If your
>   directive format is line-oriented, it is good form to ignore trailing
>   spaces and tabs on lines. The metarule is that the interpretation of
>   the file should not depend on distinctions a human eye can't see.
>
> Treat multiple blank lines and comment lines as a single blank line.
>   If the input format uses blank lines as separators between records,
>   you probably want to ensure that a comment line does not end a record.
>
> Lexically treat the file as a simple sequence of whitespace-separated
>   tokens, or lines of tokens. Complicated lexical rules are hard to
>   learn, hard to remember, and hard for humans to parse. Avoid them.
>
> But, support a string syntax for tokens with embedded whitespace. Use
>   single quote or double quote as balanced delimiters. If you support
>   both, beware of giving them different semantics as they have in shell;
>   this is a well-known source of confusion.
>
> Support a backslash syntax for embedding unprintable and special
>   characters in strings. The standard pattern for this is the
>   backslash-escape syntax supported by C compilers. Thus, for example,
>   it would be quite surprising if the string "a\tb" were not interpreted
>   as a character ‘a’, followed by a tab, followed by the character ‘b’.

So after reading, it seems the following is allowed

```sh
groovy 2.4.1
groovy 2.4.1 # inline comment
# a comment line


# the lines before are blank lines
```

But what about something like

```sh
    # a comment line preceeded by some whitespace
    groovy 2.4.1 # the line starting with leading spaces
```

Should I also support something like this?

Comment: These days I would advise using an off-the-shelf format rather than inventing your own. Consider [TOML](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml) or [YAML](https://yaml.org/), which have detailed specs and parsers available in pretty much every programming language.

Comment: If you're writing the program that's going to read the config file, then the format of the config file is up to you.  Though keep in mind any other programs (or users) that will need to (re)use the config file, in which case I'd probably want to use a more standard format (at a minimum get rid of leading white space). If you plan to keep multiple attributes on a single line (nothing wrong with that) then I'd want to give some thought to what character(s) you plan to use as a delimiter (eg, if an attribute can contain white space then you don't want to use white space as a delimiter).

Comment: The rules tend to fall out of how you write the parser — historically, that's certainly what happened.  So, for example, the parser might look for hash symbols and zap it with a null byte; then check whether there is any non-blank material on the line.  Using `sscanf(buffer, "%s %s %s", key, value, junk)` would ignore leading white space, break the key-word on white space, and check for trailing junk after the value (which it might ignore, or complain about).  For simple `key value` settings, that's quite effective. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_  It gets harder if you need to be able to include `#` in values, or deal with spaces in the values, or multiline values, but not much harder.  Generally, aim to be flexible in what you accept, but strict in the output you produce if your code ever generates a run-control file.  Consider whether you should adopt one of the standard formats — YAML, JSON, `.ini` file, etc.  But there are plenty of alternatives to choose from.